# how do i replace "all-day" text in dayview?

Tags: fullcalendar

I've tried to put `allDayText: 'LOL',` into the var defaults without any success, right after the header.

Does someone know where to but it if i want "LOL" instead of "all-day"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you should use the Answer linked in comments which is higher voted than mine and does not require editing the source JavaScript.

---

If you open the fullCalendar.js and look at the very first sections of the file there is something tagged as

```
//locale
```

there you will find something like

```
buttonText: {
    prev: '&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;',
    next: '&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;',
    prevYear: '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;',
    nextYear: '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
    today: 'today',
    month: 'month',
    week: 'week',
    day: 'day'
},
```

Change the today to

```
today: 'LOL!',
```

et viola!

If you want to change the text dynamically from the client side use the jquery like this

```
$('.fc-button-today span span').html('lollllll');
```

Comment: **Do not use this answer**. It is **far** better to use [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6111463/229044) which does not require that you modify the original FullCallendar source code.

Comment: Hehehe, answered 1 day after this question. Cant blame it on not being in the API :) Although, today it has considerably changed any way in V2.

Comment: It would rather use fullCalendar({}) method than modifying the HTML contents crudely.

Comment: Use allDayText: 'LOL'

Answer (score 14):

This should do it:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    allDayText: 'LOL'
})
```

Answer (score 8):

It works for me:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    allDayText: 'XXXXX'
})
```

Advice: Never change the *full-calendar.js* file. Set up something in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY and **eventRender**

```
eventRender: function(event, element){

element.children(':first-child').text("new text");

},
```

Answer (score -4):

In `Main.Js`, find `allDayText="all-day"` and replace with `allDayText="LOL"`.